# I want to store the contents of a .dat file located on an external memory device (sd or usb) into a String?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-file, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I apologize in advance if this question or a similar question has already been resolved, but from my search on this site and others, I have failed to resolve my problem.

As the question title suggest, I wish to store the contents of a *dat file located on an external usb or sd card into a String variable within my main activity for further processing. I am new to java and android app development and only started tinkering a few days ago (I am an embedded design/robotics engineer and only have experience writing firmware in c/c++ for microcontrollers).

Could anyone suggest a way to do this, provide a code example, or provide a link to documentation or a library (or class) that I could use that would simplify things for me? I've been wrestling with this for several hours experimenting with various code snippets from the web. Please explain your response if you can, I am a newbie when it comes to java, app development, and android.

Also, do I need to edit the manifest to permit reading of files? If so, how?

Thanks in advance,

Caleb